# Is "might" the most formal/polite modal verb?

Tags: modal-verbs

We all know that in order to be polite or formal in English, we use the past tense of modal verbs.

For  e.g.

a) Could you open the windows?

b) Would you help me with this thing?

We also know "may" is also used as a modal for politeness/permission.

So, logically "might" which is the past form of "may" got to be the most polite modal verb that could be used, right? I have seen many sites that say that "might" is informal, but logically it shouldn't be so. Am I right with this line of reasoning?

Comment: See [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/54353/might-i-vs-may-i-for-permission?rq=1). _Could_ and _would_ are technically past tense, but I think this usage is more like the conditional - "I would be grateful if you would help me..."

Comment: But is "might" the most formal modal verb or not?

Comment: You'll need an answer from somewhere outside of the U.S.  Here, "might" is so outdated that if you ask for permission with "might I," it will sound like you're making a joke.

Comment: No. _May I?_ is more usual than _might I?_ and is perfectly polite.